# XSL 2.0 output only first duplicate node

Tags: xslt

I tried searching the threads related to duplicate nodes and was almost able to achieve, it avoids duplicate nodes but it outputs the last duplicate node instead of the first node in the duplicate list (hope this is making sense).
Please advise what I'm doing wrong/missing here ?

```
    =====XML =====
    <node id="j0dp1s8s">
        <name key="">ABC</name> 
        <link type="page" target="">
            <value>abc/index</value>
        </link>
    </node>
    <node id="j0dp1s8se">
        <name key="">DEF</name> 
        <link type="page" target="">
            <value>def/index</value>
        </link>
    </node>
    <node id="j0dp1s92">
        <name key="">XYZ</name> 
        <link type="page" target="">
            <value>abc/index</value>
        </link>
    </node>

    =======XSL=============
    <xsl:variable name="unique-list" select="link[not(value=following::link/value)]" />  
    <xsl:for-each select="$unique-list">
        <li><a href="#"><xsl:value-of select="../name" /></a></li>
    </xsl:for-each>

Output: 
DEF
XYZ

Desired Output:
ABC
DEF
```

Comment: If you want the first, then you want one that doesn't have a preceding node with the same value, rather than one that doesn't have a following node with the same value. However, this way of eliminating duplicates is incredibly inefficient, and in XSLT 2.0, for-each-group is the right tool for the job.

Comment: You were right, the grouping function is incredible. Thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Prolog**

- Your source XML is not valid. Element `name` can't be closed by `label` *[deprecated]*
- I do not show your mistakes, I just provide you a much simpler and working code
- I added a root `nodes` to make your source XML valid

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="nodes">
        <ul>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="node" group-by="link/value">
              <li><a href="#"><xsl:value-of select="name" /></a></li>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </ul>        
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Therefore you can use XSLT 2, take the lovly functionality of it. https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-for-each-group

Comment: Thank you, the grouping function worked! Appreciate your help. I have updated the xml to fix the matching node for anyone to reference.